# VBA: Check if the file exists using DIR() failes in windows 7 in aliased directory

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a file that is located in "C:\Users\kris_r\Application Data\PovX.ini". Just  anticipating the questions - this path is properly shown in Watch fram..

The function below works on my Windows XP and MS Word 2010 without any problem:

```
Public Function FileExists(filename As String) As Boolean
     If (Dir(filename, vbNormal Or vbReadOnly Or vbHidden Or vbSystem Or vbArchive OR vbAlias) = "") Then
        FileExists = False
     Else:
        FileExists = True
     End If
End Function
```

However on Windows 7 this directory is an alias for "C:\Users\kris_r\AppData\Roaming\". If I run above code it generates following error : ***Runtime error '52': Bad file or number***

I wrote *FileSystemObject*-based procedure that works:

```
Public Function FileExists(filename As String) As Boolean
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(filename) Then FileExists = True Else FileExists = False
End Function
```

so programing problem is solved. However I do not understand why, even with option *vbAlias*, the DIR() method is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Because `vbAlias` is for Macintosh only.

Please see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264691.aspx)

```
Constant    Value   Description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
vbNormal    0       Normal (default for Dir and SetAttr)
vbReadOnly  1       Read-only
vbHidden    2       Hidden
vbSystem    4       System file
vbVolume    8       Volume label
vbDirectory 16      Directory or folder
vbArchive   32      File has changed since last backup
vbAlias     64      On the Macintosh, identifier is an alias.
```

Comment: ok so clearly vbAlias was wrong, but why it doesn't work for links?